# How to replace html?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I'm wondering how I could replace html in javascript but I need it to work for tampermonkey, Here's some of the scripts I used

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Example";
```

and

```
var element = document.getElementById("h1");
element.innerHTML = "Example"
```

I've tried these scripts with tampermonkey but they end up not working and I get a error, here's the error I get

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (anonymous function) @ (program):2
```

Can someone help me out please? it'd be appreciated :D

Comment: @KrisRoofe Huh? I lost tag? I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused

Comment: post your code, or run your js code in the console, and see the info.

Comment: Kk I'll do that

Comment: Since it is getting `null` for `getElementById()` call, the element doesn't exist or your code is firing before it's made. Are you making sure the script is run after the dom is ready? Either by setting tampermonkey settings to inject the script after dom loaded, or using something like an onload event?

Comment: Ok here `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…) (anonymous function) @ VM16074:1` @KrisRoofe

Comment: If you ran that in the console, then there is no element in the page with an id attribute set to `h1`, ie `<div id="h1"></div>`.

Comment: ```<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>```

```document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";```

Like here ```p1``` the ```id``` or ```h1``` should be an id.

Comment: I did put the id... @aavrug

Comment: @HelenRider Try with some custom name not use reserved keywords like ```id``` or ```h1```.

Comment: @aavrug I have... :/ I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @HelenRider can you post your html part for the `div` you are trying to replace.